# Aiogram 2.25. Does not work in web app data

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

I use aiogram = 2.25. I am trying to work with the Telegram web application. All handlers are registered in a separate. I can't get data from the web application, although there are updates.

handler.py

```py
dp.register_message_handler(application_from_web_app, content_types='web_app_data')
```

application_submission.py

```
async def application_from_web_app(message: Message):
    logging.warning(message.web_app_data.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types="web_app_data")
async def get_data(webAppMes):
    print(webAppMes)
```

But carefully, the `sendData` method works only available for Web Apps launched via a **Keyboard button**.